# Url.Action does not give the expected result. Unwanted route values remain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes

I have a MVC3 app with several routes. Two of them are defined like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "System/{name}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Systems", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "Carrier/{name}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Carriers", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Now, in my menu I have two links to these routes that are created using Url.Action:

```
Url.Action("Index","Systems")
Url.Action("Index","Carriers")
```

Now when i start the application, everything seems fine, and the links in the menu show as `/System/` and `/Carrier/`, and that is the expected value.

However, when i browse to for example `/System/MySystem` in the web page i would still want the links to point to the same place, but now they point to `/System/MySystem` and `/Carrier/MySystem`.

I have tried lots of things to keep the link from using the name from the route value, but to no avail. The strangest case i experienced was when i tried this:

```
Url.Action("Index","Systems", new{name = (string)null})
```

Now the link showed up as

```
/System?name=MySystem
```

Are there any good way here to make sure that the name value from the route values does not interfer with these links in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed the `Url.` helpers reuse the previously given route parameters.

As a workaround (I hope that there is a more elegant solution...) you can remove the `name` entry from the `RouteData.Values` in your view:

So before calling you `Url.Action` in your view:

```
Url.Action("Index","Systems")
Url.Action("Index","Carriers")
```

Remove the prefilled `name` from the `RequestContext`:

```
@{
     Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Remove("name");
}
```

It's also an workaround but if you slightly modify your routes with providing a default null value for your `name` segment:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "System/{name}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Systems", action = "Index", name = (string)null }
);
routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "Carrier/{name}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Carriers", action = "Index", name = (string)null }
);
```

Your original solution ("nulling" the `name` in the `Url.Action`) will also work :

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Systems" , new {name = (string)null} )
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant as well, but at least this gets the job done. Thanks.